# ATI Radeon HD 5770 GPU OpenGL 4.1 support?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, ati

I have a ATI Radeon HD 5770 GPU on a 2012 Mac Pro.

When I run the following code in my program:

```
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
    ATI Radeon HD 5770 OpenGL Engine
    ATI Technologies Inc.
    2.1 ATI-1.24.35
    1.20
```

But using OpenGL Extensions Viewer I get the following
[image]

Is there a way I can use 4.1? Why does it keep telling me that the version is 2.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you initialize the OpenGL context, you have the possibility to request a Compatibility profile (up to GL 2.1), or a Core Profile.

You need to enable a Core context to use OpenGL 4.1 functionalities.
The process to achieve this depends on the library which creates the context (SDL, GLU, Apple's GL framework etc.), but it is often a simple flag to pass to the init function.

Comment: I am using GLFW as my windowing system and I've added the following lines of code:         `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` But I keep getting the same output of 2.1

Comment: You need to call these before the call to `glfwCreateWindow`, is this what you have tried?